# C# Socket.Connected property is changed to false after calling Socket.Receive

Tags: c#, sockets

```
int readCount;
byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
SocketError socketError;

TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
tcpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500; // #1
// tcpClient.Client.Connected is **true** here.
readCount = tcpClient.Client.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, out socketError); // reacCount > 0
// tcpClient.Client.Connected is **false** here.
```

If #1 is replaced with **tcpClient.Client.Blocking = false;**, tcpClient.Client.Connected has correct value(true).

---

I've set `Socket.ReceiveTime` property to 100 and invoked `Socket.Receive()`. `Receive()` returned integer value greater than zero. No exception occurred.
After I do my job with copied buffer - I didn't user any of Socket related methods -, Socket.Connected property has been changed to false.
Why?

Comment: Have you checked SocketError?

Answer (score 6):

The key might be in what [TcpClient.Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected.aspx) really does:

> The Connected property gets the
>   connection state of the Client socket
>   **as of the last I/O operation**. When it
>   returns false, the Client socket was
>   either never connected, or is no
>   longer connected.
>
> Because the Connected property only
>   reflects the state of the connection
>   as of the most recent operation, you
>   should attempt to send or receive a
>   message to determine the current
>   state. After the message send fails,
>   this property no longer returns true.
>   Note that this behavior is by design.
>   You cannot reliably test the state of
>   the connection because, in the time
>   between the test and a send/receive,
>   the connection could have been lost.
>   Your code should assume the socket is
>   connected, and gracefully handle
>   failed transmissions.

So when you're not blocking and by the time you're checking the Connected value, it's possible the read wasn't finished therefore Connected is still at it's old value.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if the remote host is no longer connected to the socket. Is there a timeout on the other side of the connection which might've been exceeded?